# Haystack search with foreign key

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am building a Django app where users can search other's blogs based on keywords that appear in the title or content of their posts.  I understand that Haystack is a good option for doing these types of searches.

However, I would also like for the users to be able to filter the results by the blogs they are "following" which is stored as a many to many relationship between users and blogs.  Since Haystack back ends do not store foreign key relationships what are my options?

I am new to this so I thought of the following options, which are probably not the most efficient.

1. Search all the blogs for the given keywords to get a set of post results.  Then query the database for all followed blogs and filter them by the keyword results.
   I am not sure how well this would work if there are a lot, thousands of results in the keyword search.
2. Ad the ID of the users who are following a blog to all the blog posts' content.  Then search for the posts matching the keywords and the logged in user's ID.
   This would cause a lot of duplication of data and it seems like a dirty hack.

Is there any standard way to combine foreign key queries with text search queries?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need haystack `MultiValueField`. Check the example [here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#prepare-foo-self-object).

Comment: Why not simply do :  `SearchQuerySet().filter(blog_id__in=[1,5,9]).filter(text='hello')` where `blog_id` is a field in your `PostIndex` class